# Pass variable from ARM template to Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-rm-template, terraform-provider-azure

I want to pass output from ARM template to Terraform.
Output ARM

```
        "logicAppUrl": {
             "type": "string",
            "value": "[parameters('workflows_adf_sb_ml_name')]"
         } 
    }
```

Output terraform

```
resource "azurerm_template_deployment" "adf-sb-ml" {
  name                = "adf-sb-ml"
  resource_group_name = var.rg

  depends_on = [
    null_resource.config
  ]

  template_body = file("upload_files/adf-sb-ml.json")

  parameters = {
    "connections_servicebus_name" = "servicebus"
    "workflows_adf_sb_ml_name" = "adf-sb-ml"

  }

  deployment_mode = "Incremental"

}

output "appid" {
  value = "${lookup(azurerm_template_deployment.adf-sb-ml.outputs, "logicAppUrl")}"
}
```

But I have error when run my code

> in output "appid": 2020-09-29T18:40:40.8713191Z    2:   value =
> "${[4mlookup([0mazurerm_template_deployment.adf-sb-ml.outputs,
> "logicAppUrl")}" 2020-09-29T18:40:40.8713804Z [0m
> [90m|----------------[0m 2020-09-29T18:40:40.8714398Z [0m
> [90m|[0m [1mazurerm_template_deployment.adf-sb-ml.outputs[0m is
> empty map of string[0m 2020-09-29T18:40:40.8714829Z [0m
> 2020-09-29T18:40:40.8715289Z Call to function "lookup" failed: lookup
> failed to find 'logicAppUrl'.

Comment: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/template_deployment.html
Probably the format needs to be like this...
value = azurerm_template_deployment.example.outputs["storageAccountName"]

Comment: Hi, thanks your answer. But the error stay the same.

Comment: Since the output was supposed to be a map, lookup might have worked as well. But the error says "is empty map of string" .. may be template is returning empty to terraform. It should have worked. out of ideas now. You can use 'empty' function to check, but first, i suggest you paste the complete template if any azure experts wanted to check and suggest of there is anything wrong there.

Answer (score 0):

I have a short test with your code, it works. It should work on your side or you can check if the ARM template can deploy separately without included the Terraform or you can upgrade your terraform provider to the latest version.

[image]